# The service type IHostBufferPolicySelector is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have implemented code from here: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/

Unfortunately when I add

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHostBufferPolicySelector), new NoBufferPolicySelector());
```

I get the following error:

```
The service type IHostBufferPolicySelector is not supported
```

Why is this service not supported and how do I fix it? I have a basic template project from visual studio 2013 with references to web api2 and mvc5.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception when using **add** instead of **replace** with the IHostBufferPolicySelector. I assume that this is because it only supports one IHostBufferPolicySelector.

In my case I was using Katana / Owin hosting so I didn't use GlobalConfiguration but instead HttpConfiguration in my OwinStartup class.

```
// Doesn't work
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Services.Add(typeof(IHostBufferPolicySelector), new OwinBufferPolicySelector());
```

Instead of

```
// Works
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHostBufferPolicySelector), new OwinBufferPolicySelector());
```